# Assigning object to a new class

Tags: php, object

I have a class:

```
$b = new Model();
```

And I have a different class:

```
$c = new Model();
```

I want `$b` to be `$c`.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy an object by value / clone an object in PHP 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330215/how-to-copy-an-object-by-value-clone-an-object-in-php-5)

Comment: Did you mean cloning it or referencing it ?

Comment: @w35l3y i assume thats the answer yes.

Comment: Note that `$a` and `$b` are not *classes*, they are *instances* of the class `Model`.

Answer (score 1):

`$b = $c`  <s>$b now references $c</s> both refer the the same instance*

`$b = clone $c;` <s>$b is a copy of $c</s> each refers to a different instance of the Model*

*improved by [Ryan Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184785/ryan-vincent)

Comment: being 'picky' - actually, `$b = $c;`  both refer the the same instance and not to each other.    `$b = clone $c;` each refers to a different instance of the `Model`